# JavaFX: обновление UI данными из другого касса

Tags: javafx

Всем привет. Недавно начал изучать яву. Пишу приложение для компа и телефона - интеграция системной инфы, уведомление, смс, звонки (в будующем).
В общем на телефоне обновлять UI можно через бродкасты, а на десктопе как? 
JavaFX напускает класс и нужно, чтобы контроллер обновил lable на полученное через этот класс значение. Другой класс это сервер сокет, который соединяется с телефоном и получает данные, которые нужно вывесте в окне JavaFX.

Контроллер:

```java
package com.UI;

import com.connect.Server.Srv;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonUI;
import javax.swing.text.TableView;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import static javafx.scene.input.DataFormat.URL;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    String LOG_TAG = "Controller: ";
    @FXML
    private Button button_connect;
    private Button button_refrash;
    private TableView text_connect;
    private TableView text_battery;

    @Override
    public void initialize(java.net.URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        System.out.println(LOG_TAG + "Run Controller");
        button_connect.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                System.out.println(LOG_TAG + "Run HAndle");
                String[] str = new String[2];
                try {
                    System.out.println(LOG_TAG + "Run Srv class");
                    Srv.main(str);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println(LOG_TAG + "error run Srv");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                button_connect.setText("Stop");

            }
        });
    }
}



package com.connect.Server;

import javafx.application.Platform;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class Srv {
    public int port;
    public Srv() {
        port = 8030;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String LOG_TAG = "Srv: ";
        boolean connection = false;
        ServerConnect server = null;
        Commands command;
        String cmd = null;
        System.out.println(LOG_TAG + "Запуск Сервера");
        Srv srv = new Srv();
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println(LOG_TAG + "Ожидание Комманд");
                server = new ServerConnect(srv.port);
                server.connect();
                command = new Commands();
                while (!(cmd = server.receive()).contains("end")) {
                    if (cmd.contains("info")) {
                        System.out.println(LOG_TAG + "Получено: "   + cmd);
                        command.analyze(cmd);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(LOG_TAG + "Получено: " + cmd);
                    }
                }
                server.close();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                server.close();
                connection = false;
                System.err.println(LOG_TAG + "Connection close.");
                System.err.println(LOG_TAG + "Wait for connection.");

            }

            count++;
            System.out.println(LOG_TAG + "Соединение разорвано (" + count + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почитайте про паттерн MVC. Вам нужно создать модель и Srv будет её менять.

Comment: Спасибо! Пожалуй перейду на питон и Qt))

Comment: там используется тот же паттерн.

Comment: Я понимаю. Просто питон дружелюбнее оказался)